# Does $f(46)$ exist?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Let $\varphi(n)$ denote the totient function.

For an even positive integer $k$ , define $f(k)$ to be the smallest composite number $n$ satisfying $$\varphi(n+k)-\varphi(n)=k$$ if such a number $n$ exists. For the even numbers upto $44$ , the values are

```
2  6
4  12
6  21
8  24
10  36
12  45
14  48
16  39
18  63
20  72
22  72
24  95
26  60
28  57
30  224
32  84
34  15
36  135
38  1058
40  45
42  301
44  144
```

But I do not know whether $f(46)$ exists. If yes , we have $f(46)>10^8$.

> Does $f(46)$ exist ? If yes, what is the value ?

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A055458: “a(23) is presently unknown”

Comment: Do you want to know if it exists or do you also want to know its value?

Comment: @student91 Establishing the existence would already be nice. But the value is of course very appreciated.

Comment: Interesting that the OEIS description calls some entries "unknown", and doesn't seem to comment on existence of any entries. (Are sequence definitions with potential "gaps" even allowed there?)

Comment: @aschepler You could set a "?" or something like that at places , where the value is (or can be) undefined. I see no problem , but in fact , such sequences in OEIS are very rare. What baffles me over and oer again is that almost every somehow natural sequence seems to be present there. Using that one of $n+46$ and $n$ must be a prime power or twice a prime power allows to increase the search limit drastically.

Comment: I think , if it would be known whether $f(46)$ exists , this would have been mentioned in this way. I strongly assume that the existence is possible.

Comment: Yesterday, I wrote a small program and gave an incorrect (now deleted) answer where I omitted that we were looking for composites. I adjusted my program and let it run overnight on some idle cores, and I'll note that there are no solutions below $10^{10}$. Perhaps I now expect that $f(46)$ doesn't exist. But I'm not sure of any reasonable way to approach a proof of this fact.

Comment: If $n>4$ , then one of the numbers $n$ and $n+46$ must be of the form $p^k$ or $2p^k$ where $p$ is a prime and $k$ a positive integer. With this , we can probably push the limit to $10^{16}$ or even beyond that.